# solving quadratic congruence but overflows

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

I am solving $x^2 \equiv a\pmod{p}$, here $a = 73$ and $p = 370370384407407431$.

My Mathematica code is

```
x = Mod[a^((p + 1)/4), p]
```

but it overflows.

Is there anything I can do to reduce the algorithm so that it can solve the large numbers? Thank you a lot!

Comment: @Moo thank you so much! this function is sooo amazing!

Comment: @Moo but what should I do if the original code was Mod[x*2^((p - 1)/4), p]?

Comment: Try http://mathematica.stackexchange.com.